# How to recover messages in Akka Actors now that Durable Mailboxes are removed?

Tags: scala, akka

I was working with the latest version of Akka when I noticed that durable mailboxes are now removed from Akka.

I need to make sure that my messages are recovered upon a restart after crash. Is there an alternate way to work without durable mailboxes or a custom implementation by someone else.

I also tried Akka Persistence but it replays the messages and I don't want to send the same messages twice in the event of a crash given that all messages are expensive to perform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is not exactly a solution to work with Akka Actors, it does solve the original problem in question here.

Instead of using Akka here, I believe it's a better idea to use something like Kafka along with reactive streams with something like `akka/reactive-kafka`.

A system like that is very good for persistence, and offers very good semantics for preserving the message queue on a crash. This is way better than storing the message somewhere that is to be processed, and in general performs better.

It does not have to be Kafka, but any backend that can plug with a reactive stream (Akka's implementation or otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

[Akka Persistence](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/persistence.html) replays events that were created based on received commands. Events are generated from command messages after validation and shouldn't be able to create invalid actor states.

This means that not the initial received messages (commands) are necesarilly replayed but you can persist events that are cheaper to apply to reconstruct the state of an actor after the crash. In addition you can use [snapshots](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/persistence.html#Snapshots) to recover state directly.

**Edit:**
As mentioned i the comments it is true that only the state of the actor is persisted and survives the crash. This state only reflects the consumed messages and not those that still reside in the actors mailbox.

However instead of pushing messages to an actor which would then be stored in a durable mailbox an alternative might be for the 'recipient' to pull messages from a persistent actor which stores the list of messages as part of his state.

[UntypedPersistentActorWithAtLeastOnceDelivery](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.1/java/persistence.html#At-Least-Once_Delivery) as part of akka persistence offers another possibility where the sender takes care of persisting messages.

I realize that those are no drop-in replacements for durable mailboxes as they require rethinking the system. Pulling work from the consumers has worked for me so far. Initially we also considered message Queue products (RabbitMQ with durable queues) but since our initial work items come from a db we can deal with an akka crash without durable messages.

Comment: Persistence feature is different from durable mailbox. You still have in-memory queue which will be lost if node crashes and message has not be consumed (to be persisted).